# Getting error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_time' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I got the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_time' referenced before assignment" when running the code below. How can I solve this issue?

I use Spyder (Python 2.7), Windows 7 Ultimate.
[My full code line here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPTLC.png)

Comment: Post the full traceback, I don't see `start_time` being referenced before it is assigned in the code you posted.  The error means at some point you set start_time to something, but before that happened you tried to reference it, which isn't possible because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Comment: Hi ! I have posted again my full code in the link above, can you please check it.Thank you

Comment: Unindent line 326 and that will fix it I think

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code:

> **exception UnboundLocalError**
>   Raised when a reference is made to a local variable in a function or method, but no value has been bound to that variable. This is a subclass of NameError. [[reference]](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#UnboundLocalError)

So in this example:

```py
counter = 0

def count():
    counter += 1
    return counter

count()
```

You would get an UnboundLocalError because even though counter is assigned up top, within the scope of the function (locally) it is not.  It is *referenced* before it has been assigned.

Likely in your code, `start_time` is being evaluated or added to or something else before it has actually been assigned, i.e. before it holds any value.

Comment: Thanks to your comment! As the link attached in my question, could you help me to find out where I should amend the code? thank you